# jQuery Ajax jSON set variable array value to inside ajax JSON

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I'm confusing to set variable with array value to ajax json.

I have this variable on JS:

```
var complaintsData = [
    { complaint: "Pizza is cold", count: 780 },
    { complaint: "Inadequate cheese quantity", count: 120 },
    { complaint: "Not baked properly", count: 52 },
    { complaint: "Delayed delivery", count: 1123 },
    { complaint: "Damaged delivery", count: 321 },
    { complaint: "Incorrect billing", count: 89 },
    { complaint: "Wrong size delivered", count: 222 }
];
```

Now I need to get the variable array value from DB.
Then I have ajax to get data from db:

```
setInterval(function()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "load2",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (jsonStr)
        {
            for(var i=0; i<jsonStr.complaint.length; i++)
            {
                var complaintsData = [
                    { complaint: jsonStr.complaint[i], count: jsonStr.count[i] }
                ];
            }
        }
    });
}, 3000);
```

I tried to run above code, but it's not working.

My question, how can I set `var complaintsData` to inside ajax load?

Comment: can you post the data which is jsonStr from server as well in your question?
Also, do you want to update complaintsData array or you want to just replace with the  newer data?

Comment: Hi @SumodhNair I updated my question

Answer (score 2):

In order to add data to an array, you need to use `push` method

```
 var complaintsData  = [];

    setInterval(function()
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: "load2",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (jsonStr)
                {   
                    for(var i=0; i<jsonStr.complaint.length; i++)
                    {
                        complaintsData.push ({ complaint: jsonStr.complaint[i], count: jsonStr.count[i] })
                    }
                }
            });
        }, 3000);
```

Comment: can you debug your code after the loop is over and see what complaintsData is?

Comment: Is it possible to add it on setInterval? I tried to remove setInterval and it can be show

Comment: Why do you want to use setInterval? Do you want to call the server everytime after 3 secs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180421/discussion-between-hidayurie-dave-and-sumodh-nair).